# Visual studio “Could not complete the action.” On any intellisense action

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I try to do something on .ascx control like creating `<%@ Register` tag or try to use shortcut `Ctrl+K+F` VS throws error "Could not complete the action."
Nothing helps: reset settings, clearing caches and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Format on paste" at Tools > Options > JavaScript/TypeScript > Formatting > General.
[image]